# Implementing IAutorizationFilter in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, filter

I'm trying to build filters on `ASP.NET MVC 4` based on `IAuthorizationFilter` to limit access to certain controllers.

The idea is, that if an end-user of the web-app have the appropriate privilege his access is allowed, in other case, he don't.

So I'm trying at final, to get its BOOL privileges based on `User.Identity.Name` and then check if he has the right or not.

Do I need to implement filters as many as I have BOOL privilges or only one filter can do the work?
How do I to implement this? Any brilliant idea, please?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to do that. How you determine the privileges of each user can be either done within `OnAuthorization` or refactored into a separate static method and called within `OnAuthorization`.

But, when you use use the custom authorize attribute for either `Action` method or for a `Controller`, you should be able to say that only users with `Create` permission can access the `Action` or users with `Read` permission can access this `controller`. Please take a look at this blog post.

http://codeutil.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/forms-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-4/#mvc-implement-custom-authorization-filter

you will notice there are two Variables defined

```
public int StartTime { get; set; }
public int EndTime { get; set; }
```

instead, you can use

```
public bool AllowRead {get;set;}
public bool AllowWrite {get;set;}
```

then use the authorize attribute as follows

```
[HttpPost]
[CustomAuthorize(AllowRead = false, AllowWrite = true)]
public ActionResult Create(Model model)
{
    //your code
}
```

above is just one way of doing it. Another method is to use an enum flag. Please take a look at this answer.

[How could I use my own database table for MVC 4 user control (and authorizing with boolean fields in role table)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851606/how-could-i-use-my-own-database-table-for-mvc-4-user-control-and-authorizing-wi/17853331#17853331)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The privileges are stored into a table (class) which is related with the memberships table. So, I'm trying to get the privileges of the current logged in user and check if he/she has the right to execute a controller action. A privilege allows to take advantage of all of a controller's methods.