# How to develop action filter controller or action method specific

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, custom-action-filter

i was trying to develop a custom action filter which will check cookie is enable or not. if cookie is not enable then redirect use to a specific error page.here is my code.

```
public class CheckCookieAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {

       public string prmAction{get;set;}

       public string prmController{get;set;}


        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookie["YourCookie"]==null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectToAction(prmAction,prmController)
        }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            //The action filter logic - after
        }
    }
```

now i am using like

```
[CheckCookie(prmAction="MyAction",prmController="MyController")]
```

due to lack of good knowledge i am not being able to develop attribute driven check for cookie enable or disable.

i want to develop a code in such a way as a result i should not pass any controller name or action name. i like to use code like

```
[HttpPost]
 [CheckCookieAttribute]
 public ActionResult Save(Person oPerson)
 {
        return View();
 }

[CheckCookieAttribute]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
public ActionResult Index()
{return View();}

public ActionResult About()
{return View();}
}
}
```

where i will not provide any name of controller or action name. just guide me what i need to change in my code. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that what you are trying to accomplish is already built into ASP.NET MVC.

I would use the [Authorize] attribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) where you want to check if the user has a cookie.

If you want to redirect the user to a specific controller/action when the user is not authorized, you can use the following attribute instead:

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new
                    {
                        controller = "Error",
                        action = "Unauthorized"
                    })
                );
    }
}
```

See [ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Authorize Attribute with Permission Codes (without roles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264496/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-with-permission-codes-without-roles)

Then you would use it by using:

```
[HttpPost]
[AuthorizeUser]
public ActionResult Save(Person oPerson)
{
    return View();
}
```

Or if you want exactly what you asked for you can do it this way:

```
public class CheckCookieAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["YourCookie"] == null)
            {                                
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { {"controller", "MyController"}, {"action", "MyAction"}});                
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            //The action filter logic - after
        }
    }
```

Comment: u said : I would use the [Authorize] attribute...where you want to check if the user has a cookie.so i like to know when i attach any [AuthorizeUser] attribute with action method then how can i check the cookie is enable or not at client machine? please guide me. thanks

Comment: Basically that's what [AuthorizeUser] does (and validates the cookie and so on), but if you want to check for a specific cookie set on the client, you can use the last code snippet in the answer.