# How go to authorize method ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm testing Basic Http Authentication. I try go to a page, But when I go to "books/get", I see nothing. Why? What I should add?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace WebApiTest.Controllers
{
    public class BooksController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize]
        public String Get()
        {
            String res = "Hello";
            return res;
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you've decorated the method with `Authorize`, you won't actually be able to access that action result unless you're authenticated. If you see nothing, then you need to configure your `loginUrl` inside your web.config, something like:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="http://yoursite.co.uk/login timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Comment: OP wants `Basic Http Authentication`. I think he needs a custom `ActionFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

`[Authorize]` is a default implementation in MVC framework. It uses forms authentication mentioned by @mattytommo

```
 public class AuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, AuthorizationFilter
```

and uses

```
protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
}
```

If you want to create your own in order to customize authorization you can check [ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Authorize Attribute with Permission Codes (without roles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264496/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-with-permission-codes-without-roles)

[Refer MSDN for Deriving](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx#deriving_from_authorizeattribute)