# How to Redirect to Another Action in an Action.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I'm trying to change the current view via controller.

```
public ActionResult login(string str)
{
  if(str=="true")
  {
    return View("index");
  }
  else
  {
    return View("error");
  }
}

public ActionResult index()
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult error()
{
  return View();
}
```

I have all this actions in the same controller and the view files in the same directory.

Comment: is the primary intent here to determine if the user is allowed to access Index, or are you specifically attempting to determine the results of an if/else statement inside of an ActionMethod?

Comment: What you have will display either the index or error page when they access the /login page depending on the value of `str`. Was there something else you wanted to do?

Comment: i have my own backend library that turns me a response which i can see is it succeed or failed that corresponds to user can login or not.After i check user can login i want to navigate my user to my main page which is in an another view called it index.

Comment: so what is your problem? what is not working? the code above works

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying redirect to another action from one. You can use `RedirectToAction(..)` function the achive this.

For example, if your action defined like this:

```
public ActionResult Action1()
{
   /* code omitted */
}
```

You can redirect to it like this any where in an action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action1");
```

If you want to redirect to an action which is in another controller, you can use

```
return RedirectToAction("Action1", "ControllerName");
```

If the action takes parameters, or route parameters you can use

```
return RedirectToAction("Action1", "ControllerName", new { param1 = value1, param2 = value2 });
```

***BTW,*** If you're trying to implement an authentication mechanism, this is the wrong approach. You should use [Authorize] attribute or develop custom authentication. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13284548/438570).

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that you are looking to validate a user before allowing them access to Index, MVC has a built-in class attribute that you can use which will reroute the user to a login form for you.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{return View();}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName");
```