# Demo User Wtih Minimum Effort In Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, demo

In asp.net mvc 4 project, there are a lot of pages that have create-update-insert-delete events. I try to build a demo user. **But I don't want to update my code in every button click.** If this demo user logins then only can select. Must not CRUD.

How can i do with minimum code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into creating a custom [Authorize] Attribute.

You would put that on each controller at the top and the attribute code will run for each controller action checking if the current user should have access to it.

[MSDN for background]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

[Stackoverflow answer]

[ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Authorize Attribute with Permission Codes (without roles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264496/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-with-permission-codes-without-roles)

Comment: I thougt that. I will create a user in database which have only **select** authority. If demo user logins then use this connectionstring. **Changing connectionString dynamically** is logical and possible? Thanks.