# Cannot use User.Identity.GetUserId in Custom attributes in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-attributes

I am trying to write a custom attribute that can validate if a user is authorized for certain controller or not. Found this link [ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Authorize Attribute with Permission Codes (without roles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264496/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-with-permission-codes-without-roles) here on Stackoverflow. My problem is I am not able to use `User.Identity.GetUserId`to write any kind of query  . It throw error that `"Error 1   The name 'User' does not exist in the current context"`. Adding `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;` also did not helped. I basically want to do check if certain AccessLevel is valid for logged in user or not. For this later I was planning to go to database and query for logged in user. I am learning this so please advise if I am doing this totally wrong.

Below is the code I am starting with.

Thanks.

```
    public class UserAuthorizeAttributes : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string AccessLevel { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {         
            // Check if valid credentials  are there for selected User.Identity.GetUserId() in database
            { return true ; }
            else
            { return false; }

        }
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/TimeShare/Account/LogOn");

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

So I was planning to use in controllers as below

```
[UserAuthorizeAttributes(AccessLevel ="UserAdmin")] 
public class XXXXController : Controller {
 }
```

Comment: So just found out that  `httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();`  gives me ID. Not sure if this is the right way to go.

Comment: There is a roles based attribute you can use for roles like UserAdmin.  May be easier since there is no code you have to manage.

Comment: I actually have to write custom that is on top of role based. This is the reason just role is based i not enough. Thanks.

Comment: You are right with pulling the user ID from the httpContext.  This is the way that your controllers are doing it behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. But my question is why is `User.Identity.GetUserId` not working?

Comment: Because there is no `User` in this context.  You could create it yourself like `var User = httpContext.User;` but either way, it is one in the same, just accessed differently.