# Using enums like strings dot net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums

so i have the next problem. I have a controller and some user roles. I'm using string when i have  `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` but i want to use an enum like that because if i change the name of role i will modify in one single     place. 
I already tried `Roles=UserRoles.Admin.ToString()`, where UserRoles is my enum but i'm getting an error. I already read aricles from here but seems that no one helps me to solve my problem.

Could you help me with any suggestion?

Comment: Create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` see something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264496/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-with-permission-codes-without-roles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Whatever
{
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params UserRoles[] userRoles)
        {
            Roles = string.Join(",", userRoles);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as you would usually use the `AuthorizeAttribute`, like this:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Whatever
{
    [CustomAuthorize(UserRoles.Admin, UserRoles.Whatever)]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but you need to do a little work.

- Create you own custom attribute implementing `IAuthorizationFilter` (as `AuthorizeAttribute` does)
- Accept your enumeration in its constructor (or via a property)
- Forward operations to a contained instance of `AuthorizeAttribute`

(The whole filter mechanism is extensible to allow this kind of thing.)

However, what I have done in the past, to deal with this is to define a series of constant strings which are passed to the attribute's instances. Thus keeping the names central.