# How can I use MVC controller annotations conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using Asp.Net MVC 5 and Identity v2, I have a controller action like:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SemiSecureAction(string parameter)
{
   var model = SomeService.InitModel(parameter);
   // some controller logic
   return View(model);
}
```

I need to have that `[Authorize]`attribute on this action *only if the parameter meets a condition*. (e.g. `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter)`)

That is, I need to authorize a user only if the action's parameter meets a condition, and I need to have the same behavior in that case as the `[Authorize]` attribute does (e.g. redirect to login page with a `returnUrl`, etc.).

How can I do this? How can I use MVC controller annotations conditionally?

Comment: Build your own custom attribute that inherits and expand Authorize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're better off writing your own custom attribute that implements AuthorizeAttribute. Here is a SO example of how to do that

[ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Authorize Attribute with Permission Codes (without roles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264496/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-with-permission-codes-without-roles).

What you describe in your question is impossible to achieve. By the time the parameter `parameter` has been passed into the action method, `[Authorize]` has already executed.

By creating a custom attribute, you would have access to the route values passed to the action method (which you could pick up from the passed `HttpContextBase` given to `AuthorizeCore()`). You can then perform any logic you like, based on the value of `parameter`.