# Claims athorization service API usability

Tags: c#, authorization, claims-based-identity, usability, fluent-interface

Is the following API of a *claims authorization service* ok, from the point of view of usability?

```
/* before UPDATE it was like this:  
var canEdit = Authz.ForNewRequest()
    .WithActionName("edit")
    .WithResourceName("project")
    .WithResourceClaim("DepartmentId","21")
    .CheckAccess(); */

//UPDATE:
var deptId = SomehowGetDepartmentIdAtRuntime(targetProject);
var canEdit = Authz.ForNewRequest()
    .WithActionName("edit")
    .WithResourceName("project")
    .WithResourceClaim("DepartmentId",deptId)
    .CheckAccess();

 if (canEdit) 
 {
     //edit project
 }
```

And configuration like this:

```
 var authorizationModel = Authorization.ConfigNamespace.AuthzConfig
     .LoadAuthorizationModelFromXml("authz.xml");

 Authorization.ConfigNamespace.AuthzConfig
     .SetApplicationAuthorization(authorizationModel);
```

Or custom configuration like this:

```
 var authzCustomConfig = Authorization.ConfigNamespace.AuthzConfig
     .NewCustomConfiguration()
     .WithCustomClaimBasedFactFunctions(claimBasedFunctions)
     .WithCustomClaimProviders(claimProviders)
     .WithCustomCompositeFactFunctions(compositeFactFunctions)
     .WithCustomObligations(obligations);

 var authorizationModel = Authorization.ConfigNamespace.AuthzConfig
     .LoadAuthorizationModelFromXml("authz.xml", authzCustomConfig);

 Authorization.ConfigNamespace.AuthzConfig
     .SetApplicationAuthorization(authorizationModel);
```

---

Basically, the question is about the top part of the iceberg, i.e. how to use the service, but not how to implement or design the inner part. But just in case, here are a couple of general words about this service:

This service gives an answer of `true`/`false` for the given *authorization request*.

*Authorization request* has information about:

- Action (action name, for example)
- Resource (resource name, resource properties)
- Subject (user name, user id, user roles, user properties)

Due to the fact that i use `Microsoft.IdentityModel`:

- The properties of an *action*, *resource*,  or a *subject* are presented as *Claims*. Approximately, a claim is an object, which has a value, value name, and value type. For example, a claim for a user could have the following info: ("UserName", "Andrey", "string").
- The *authorization request* is the `AuthorizationContext` class from the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims` namespace.

Two more things to consider:

- I'd like this service to be a general solution, which could fit not only to one certain project.
- Logic could be involved in order to understand if a condition for the permission decision is met or not.

That's why custom logic might be injected. Those `claimBasedFunctions`, `claimProviders`, `compositeFactFunctions`, and `obligations` are the *custom logic*. But they don't really matter for the question, just some custom confuguration elements, implementations of the interfaces, which are defined in the authorization assembly. The question is not about what they should be, or how they should work. You can think of them as of any interface implementatons that have to be injected.

---

Thanks!

P.S. this question is off-topic for the *Code Review* site.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your description correctly, the following code means: "If you want to `edit` a `project`, you need a claim with name `DepartmentId` that has a value of `21`.

```
 var canEdit = Authz.ForNewRequest()
     .WithActionName("edit")
     .WithResourceName("project")
     .WithResourceClaim("DepartmentId","21")
     .CheckAccess();

 if (canEdit) 
 {
     //edit project
 }
```

This statement would be at the start of your `Edit` action in your `Project` controller in case you were building an MVC application.

If my interpretation is correct, I would advise you to remove the `WithActionName` and `WithResourceName` methods. Those things can be retrieved from the context in which this code is executing. Your fluent API is too easy to copy from one method to another and forget to update those strings. I would look at a custom [`authorize` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13264496/18044) that you attach to an action in which you checks the claims.

**UPDATE:**
I was thinking something like this:

```
public class ProjectController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [MyAuthorize("DepartmentId","21")
    public void Edit(string applicationName)
    {
        // business logic
    }
}
```

Inside the `MyAuthorize` attribute implementation you can retrieve the controller- and action names. If the developer using the attribute doesn't have to specify this, he/she can't get it wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to make it more clear for me, sorry. 21 is the _Project's department id_. Check access for _editing_ a _project_ may say _NO_. Check access for _resource_ with _departament id_ = 21 may also say _NO_. But alltogether may result in a _YES_. And _project_'s _department id_ is known at **runtime**. So do you mean to have **both**: 1) an _attribute_, declaring the _action_ and _resourse_ above a method; and 2) the `CheckAccess() //knowing dept id` call from within this method, implying that `CheckAccess()` extracts some metadata from the method's attribute above?

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it more clear (hopefully).

Comment: Thanks! It's probably a good solution, but sorry, i don't fully understand how to use it in my case. I made an update in my question in order to say: 21 is not known at compile time. It should be something like `[MyAuthorize("DepartmentId",x)]`, but i'm not sure whether this is possible with c#. My authorization is probably a bit harder one because logic is involved. For example, the project's department must be subordinate to the authenticated user's one in order to be edited.

Comment: Oh, forgot to say that there could be possibly be hundreds of different departments in a general case.

Comment: The logic in your attribute implementation can be as complex as needed. It could query some service for the needed info if necessary. My main advice was to make sure the developer has little possibility to make mistakes when doing authorization. Especially when developers do not completely understand what your canEdit statement means, they are inclined to just copy/paste it into the next method.