# ASP.NET mvc 4 authorize attribute with permission(without roles)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

i am trying control the access to views based on users privilege levels (there are no roles, only privilege levels for CRUD operation levels assigned to users from my database)

i do not know how to approach this matter except of [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
but this does not work.

```
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your Login page.";

        return View();
    }

  [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]

    public ActionResult AuditReport()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using FormsAuthentication?

Comment: Create Custom Authorize Attribute
here you have [good explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264496/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-with-permission-codes-without-roles)

Comment: @RossBush yes it located in my account controller  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);

Comment: @liran thanks im lookin thorough it now